# How do I save a file so that it's viewable for the user?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I can't save a in Xamarin.forms file so that it's visable to the user etc. in downloads or documents. I've managed to save into a hidden file using *PCL*, but i need the user to be able to see the file saved. Is there anything i can use to access the visible folders and save the file there?

This did not work:

```
string writeData = convertToString(data);
string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
string localFilename = "Data.csv";
string localPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, localFilename);
File.WriteAllText(localPath, writeData);
```

Comment: It can't be achieved on iOS. There's no external storage for iOS, you could only store files in app's own sandbox. Then list all the files in your own app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by different solutions on iOS and Android and using depencdeny to differentiate.

Android

```
     public void saveFile(string fileName, string text)
     {
        string DocumentPath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).AbsolutePath;
        string filePath = Path.Combine(DocumentPath, fileName);
        File.WriteAllText(filePath, text);
     }
```

iOS: Found some code that makes it possible to save on the iCLoud drive https://xamarinhelp.com/share-dialog-xamarin-forms/:

```
     public class Share : IShare
{
    // MUST BE CALLED FROM THE UI THREAD
    public async Task Show(string filePath)
    {
        var items = new NSObject[] { NSUrl.FromFilename(filePath) };
        var activityController = new UIActivityViewController(items, null);
        var vc = GetVisibleViewController();

        NSString[] excludedActivityTypes = null;

        if (excludedActivityTypes != null && excludedActivityTypes.Length > 0)
            activityController.ExcludedActivityTypes = excludedActivityTypes;

        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
        {
            if (activityController.PopoverPresentationController != null)
            {
                activityController.PopoverPresentationController.SourceView = vc.View;
            }
        }
        await vc.PresentViewControllerAsync(activityController, true);
    }

    UIViewController GetVisibleViewController()
    {
        var rootController = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;

        if (rootController.PresentedViewController == null)
            return rootController;

        if (rootController.PresentedViewController is UINavigationController)
        {
            return ((UINavigationController)rootController.PresentedViewController).TopViewController;
        }

        if (rootController.PresentedViewController is UITabBarController)
        {
            return ((UITabBarController)rootController.PresentedViewController).SelectedViewController;
        }

        return rootController.PresentedViewController;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

of course, you can save the file to a visible folder.
According to the documentation:
[external storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=windows#private-external-files).
For example, if you want to save the file to the Documents folder, you can obtain the path as follows:

```
Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryDocuments).AbsolutePath;
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Using dependency i get this error on Android: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: `Could not find a part of the path "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/Datafile.csv"` Any clue?

Comment: Are you sure you have 'Documents' folder in your Android device?